# how to use seperate paramenter with shortcode_atts in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new to wordpress and trying build `shortcode` with parameter using `shortcode_atts`

I have two array element foo

```
function bartag_func( $atts ) {
    $a = shortcode_atts( array(
        'name' => 'vaibhav',
        'lname' => 'kulkarni',
    ), $atts );

return $a;
}
add_shortcode( 'bartag', 'bartag_func' );
```

and i want to use name and lname as parameter from below code

```
[bartag name="Alex'" lname="joe"]
```

if nothing is passed then it should print `name as vaibhav and lname as kulkarni`
 am I doing in correct way? it is printing `Array` not as individual element.
Please let me know how to access each array element as parameter like this `[bartag name="Alex'" lname="joe"]`

Comment: You just have to define shortcode and its function, rest will be managed by wordpress. Just generate the `[bartag name="Alex'" lname="joe"]` and you are all set.

Comment: not working it is printing 'Array' keyword

Comment: Try `var_dump($atts)` inside the `bartag_func()`. will it returns empty?

Comment: array (size=2)
  'name' => string 'Alex' (length=4)
  'lname' => string 'joe' (length=3) 
I got this as result

Comment: looks perfect. then where you are facing the difficulty.

Comment: on my about us page http://localhost/wordpress/about-us-2/ i am using [bartag name="Alex" lname="joe"] this short code and want to print Alex joe  but it prints 'Array' (as word) instead of my expected output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162794/discussion-between-yash-parekh-and-vaibhav).

Answer (score 0):

As i am new to wordpress I think I was doing something in wrong way. `return $a` returning the whole array so instated of returning array I choose `return $a['name']." ".$a['lname'];` now with this code i can able to see as per my expected output